# Dynamically select date

Tags: mdx

Goal is to pass prior year if current month is 1, else pass current year.  I always want data through the prior month.  I have dynamic month logic working, just the year is causing me issues.  I am attempting this with an IIF statement but am consistently returning the current year.

```
SELECT ( { IIF( Month(Now()) = '1', Strtomember(" [Posting Date].[Year].&[" + cstr(year(dateadd('yyyy',-1,now()))) + "] "),
                                                                 Strtomember(" [Posting Date].[Year].&[" + cstr(year(now())) + "] ")) 
                                                                 } ) ON COLUMNS
```

I have verified that each `Strtomember` piece works correctly independently when I remove the IIf.  I am able to query current year and then swap the Strtomember and return current year -1.

Note: For testing purposes I have `IIF( Month(Now()) = '6'` as it is the current month at time of post.  I should return current year -1, but am returning current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the '1' to just a number 1:

Instead of `Month(Now()) = '1'`
Use `Month(Now()) = 1`

The above change works fine on my cube:

```
SELECT 
  {
    IIF
    (
      Month(Now()) = 6
     ,StrToMember
      ("[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year].&["
          + 
            Cstr(Year(Dateadd('yyyy',-1,Now())))
        + "]"
      )
     ,StrToMember
      (
          "[Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Year].&[" + Cstr(Year(Now()))
        + "] "
      )
    )
  } ON COLUMNS
```